# Create an X number of <divs> with <divs> inside it, with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get javascript to write this multiple times on the html code

```
<div id="todo>
<div class="content">

     <div class="water">
         <img src="water.png">
     </div>

    <div class="waterdata">
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, It's a simple div with two divs inside of it, and theres a local variable that determines how many times the div appears on the page. I tried using a **do while** loop to make javascript write the code above several times, but it just rewrites itself X times, so there's always only one div in my page. This is what I tried

```
function pagina(){
    do {
        var todo = document.getElementById('todo');
        todo.innerHTML = ('<div class="content"> <div class="water"><img src="water.png"> </div> <div class="waterdata">- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</div></div>');
        var peso = peso - 1;
       }
    while(peso>0);

}
```

Do you have any suggestions? It bugs me a lot :( help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are _overwriting_ the `innerHTML` of the element each time – instead, you need to _append_ to it, `.innerHTML += "…"`. Or even better, assemble the HTML content in a string variable first (`foo += "…"`), and then assign that to innerHTML after your loop.

Comment: And where do you initialize `peso`?

Comment: peso is taken from a form another html file, which then is stored on localStorage, letting this html file use it

Comment: Alright, so I took the string of code from .innerhtml and passed it onto a variable, so my code now looks like this:
    
    var divcontents = '<div class="content"> ... </div>'
    todo.innerHTML+=(divcontents);

And it does actually work! It creates another instance of my div and it appears on my webpage, but only once, It looks as if it actually wrote the code for another div, and then it just rewrote it the remaining times.

Supposing my variable *peso* = 5 , my div should appear 5 times, but it appears only two times

Answer (score 0):

```
function addDivToParent(parent, onNewLine, class, text)
{
    if (onNewLine) parent.innerHTML += "<br />";
    parent.innerHTML += "<div class=" + class + ">" + text + "</div>";
}
var water_text = "<img src='water.png' />";
var waterdata_text = "water data text";
var parentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    addDivToParent(parentDiv, true, "water", water_text);
    addDivToParent(parentDiv, true, "waterdata", waterdata_text);
}
```